# Is perfume lo Yilbash for a man

Tags: halacha, men-male, yoreh-deah, modern-times, lo-yilbash

Is there a problem of lo yilbash, prohibited cross dressing, with a man wearing perfume? Or no, since it is not a physical garment is it permissible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Din.online [explains](https://dinonline.org/2019/11/15/cologne-for-men-lo-yilbash/) that there is no problem for a men to wear perfume. However, because of Lo Yilbash, the perfume should not be a womens-perfume (Rivivos Efrayim- Tznif MIlucha pg. 284-1, Beer Sarim 6-59, Ohrl Yackov Lo tilbash 83).

> Nowadays there are many men that wear cologne, therefore halachically it isn’t Lo Tilbash for a man to wear men’s cologne, (but not a women’s perfume). However hashkafically it should be done in a way that is not attracting.

Comment: "hashkafically it should be done in a way that is not attracting." What does that mean?

Comment: Attracting attention I would guess